# Is there any site which covers Chromium OS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which site in the network covers development related questions about the [Chromium OS](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os)?

I mean questions about the OS itself, like the internals, libraries and kernel level stuff.

Also, which site covers questions from users of the Chromium OS like getting around errors, web applications, mods, personalizations ?

Comment: What kind of questions? Development on the platform? Tooling for writing software for it? Something else?

Comment: 1. SO 2. SU ? Perhaps you could be a bit more specific

Answer (score 3):

There is no dedicated Chromium OS Stack Exchange.

In general, programming questions (including issues with programming tools) belong on Stack Overflow.

Questions regarding OS setup and hardware (in a professional capacity) can go to Server Fault.

Conceptual issues (whiteboard questions) go on Programmers Stack Exchange.

General usage questions would go to Super User.

Questions specific to web applications can go to Web Apps Stack Exchange.

Comment: Surprisingly, the entire network doesnt have a Chromium-OS tag.

Comment: @AsheeshR - And yet... Guess it was never created on any of the sites. It _is_ a bit Meta.

Comment: "Questions regarding OS setup and hardware can go to Server Fault." Since when that's the case? I thought Server Fault was for...well...Servers and similar. Also Unix & Linux is appropriate for certain questions.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - Updated to reflect that SF requires professional questions (so no hobbyist issues)

Comment: Also don't forget that ChromeOS/ChromiumOS heavily relies on the cloud and Google products, so questions about certain applications can go straight to WebApps.

Comment: If someone's running ChromeOS on a server something's gone horribly wrong...

Comment: @Wooble - are you saying it can't/won't happen?

Comment: I suspect it would be impossible to ask an on topic SF question about it, anyway. The whole premise of using an OS that's just a web browser on a professional server would be laughed off the site.